# Modify doctrine 2 proxy class

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities entityA and entityB, linked with a 1 to 1 relationship

EntityB

```
Company\Bundles\EntityBundle\DataObjects\Entity\EntityB:
  type: entity
  table: notice
  fields:
    idEntityB:
      id: true
      type: string
      length: 50
      fixed: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_entityB
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY

    name:
      type: string
      length: null
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
      column: name

  oneToOne:
    EntityA:
      targetEntity: EntityA
      mappedBy: EntityB    
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

entityA

```
Company\Bundles\EntityBundle\DataObjects\Entity\EntityA:
  type: entity
  table: entityA
  fields:
    idEntityA:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_entityA
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    idEntityB:
      type: string
      length: 50
      fixed: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_entityB
  oneToOne:
    EntityB:
      targetEntity: EntityB
      joinColumn:
        name: id_entityB
        referencedColumnName: id_entityB
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

When I retrieve an instance of entityA, and then get the linked entityB, modify it and try to save its modifications like this

```
$entA = //get instance of entityA using the em's query builder
$entB = $entA->getEntityB();
$entB->setName('test');
$em->persist($entB);
```

I get the following error

```
 exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class Proxies\MyEntityNameSpaceEntityBProxy is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in .../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:142
```

It seems the error is because $entB is actually an instance of a proxy class.

Question: How can I modify $entB?

I'm using Doctrine 2.1

**Update**: added simplified yml and corrected call to $em->persist

Comment: Post here your full definition of EntityA and EntityB. Also I have a question: `$em->persist('entB');` are you really pass string to this method? Did you try to pass object `$entB`?

Comment: I added the yml. Yes, 'entB' was a typo in my post and was corrected